# NextJS cannot read jsx-loader

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, loader

I'm trying to set up new Next.js application. When i install all packages (using npx create-next-app or installing with myself like npm i -s next react react-dom) and when i start app, i always see this error:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:2)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

I read that what they wrote before and i tried to install jsx-loader and tried to set up it in webpack.config.js but it doesn't work at all. I already tried to set up project 5 times and i always get this error. Can you help me?

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm assuming you have a .babelrc somewhere up the directory tree that causes the code to be compiled incorrectly.

Comment: There is no .babelrc in my project. I don't change anything, I'm trying to run when all dependencies installs, but I'm getting that error every single time...